# Why bootstrap doesn't work for me all the time?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to copy and paste the bootstrap code that I got from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/weather/

It is #4 product. However,I am wondering whether I am doing something wrong or it is just most of free boot strap code doesn't work?

Can anyone explain this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
  </head>

 <style>
 .gradient-custom {
 /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: #ffffff;

/* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 236, 210, 1));

/* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 236, 210, 1))

 }



.carousel-indicators li {
background-color: #282828;
width: 7px;
height: 7px;
border-radius: 50%;


 }
 </style>
```

```
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100" style="color: #282828;">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-5">

      <div class="card mb-4 gradient-custom" style="border-radius: 25px;">
        <div class="card-body p-4">

          <div id="demo1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators mb-0">
              <li data-target="#demo1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Carousel inner -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-4 pb-2">
                  <div>
                    <h2 class="display-2"><strong>23°C</strong></h2>
                    <p class="text-muted mb-0">Coimbra, Portugal</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-weather/ilu3.png" width="150px">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card mb-4" style="border-radius: 25px;">
        <div class="card-body p-4">

          <div id="demo2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators mb-0">
              <li data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="0"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Carousel inner -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around text-center mb-4 pb-3 pt-2">
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>21°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>12:00</strong></p>
                    <p class="mb-0 text-muted" style="font-size: .65rem;">PM</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>2°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>1:00</strong></p>
                    <p class="mb-0 text-muted" style="font-size: .65rem;">PM</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>20°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>2:00</strong></p>
                    <p class="mb-0 text-muted" style="font-size: .65rem;">PM</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>19°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>3:00</strong></p>
                    <p class="mb-0 text-muted" style="font-size: .65rem;">PM</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>18°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>4:00</strong></p>
                    <p class="mb-0 text-muted" style="font-size: .65rem;">PM</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card" style="border-radius: 25px;">
        <div class="card-body p-4">

          <div id="demo3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators mb-0">
              <li data-target="#demo3" data-slide-to="0"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#demo3" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Carousel inner -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around text-center mb-4 pb-3 pt-2">
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>21°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>Mon</strong></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>20°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>Tue</strong></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>16°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>Wed</strong></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>17°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>Thu</strong></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-column">
                    <p class="small"><strong>18°C</strong></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>Fri</strong></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's not working BTW?

Comment: I didn't see that you included the bootstrap link in your code

Comment: what do u mean by include the bootstrap link?

Comment: it just doesnt work. only few codes are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following links inside your `<head>...</head>` section.

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!-- MDB -->
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

**OR**

If you are using the Node Package Manager for your project, try installing it using this command. `npm i mdb-ui-kit`

Always follow the [documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/getting-started/installation/) :)

Comment: oh my god... how did u do that?

Comment: First, I wanna say thank u so much for ur help. been coding for like 3 months so i do not know much of it

Comment: Happy to help Yang. btw please mark this as the correct answer. Some other person may find this useful as well :)

Comment: BTW can u explain how u did it? it seems like it is a specific link i have to install in order to use bootstrap? each bootstrap websites has their own link that needs to be install in the code?

Comment: These links are called CDNs. Yes, they have different CDN links based on their framework. I think it's better if you read this [article](https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/cdn/) to get the full understanding.